# 2 play framework application with single httpd

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0, mod-proxy, amazon-elb

I have two different applications developed in Play framework. I am trying to launch both the application in a EC2 instance with apache, ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse setup.

I have to use two different URL and SSL for each application. I could bring one of the application successfully. The other one is creating the problem. I have installed ELB with SSL incase if we need load balance the traffic by creating two replicated EC2 instances.

Kindly suggest a good way to do it. I have to use this for my Production Setup.

Comment: Guys, Can someone give me an example setup? Please, this is urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Proxypass can be used for one application means **ELB to HTTPD then to PLAY** this is for 1 application and the second you should redirect the port in ELB like port 4444 to port 5555

Comment: This might work. But I want to redirect both the url's going from ELB to HTTPD and then to their respective Play Application. In your setup, I can load balance only the first application and the second one will not be load balanced properly.